Ramsey Theorem For $\omega$-branching trees
I've see a number of papers addressing both the computability theory and combinatorics of Ramsey's theory on binary trees. The following feels like a somewhat similar question on $\omega^{< \omega}$ but it's a bit different since paths get colored based on pairs they extend.  Specifically, I'm wondering about the following question.
Given a computable perfect $\omega$ branching tree $T$ (which may include terminal nodes) and an r.e. set $S$ of pairs of strings $\sigma, \tau \in \omega^{< \omega}$ is there always a non-empty perfect $\omega$ branching sub-tree $\hat{T}$ with the property that either all pairs of paths $f, g \in [T]$ meet $S$ or all pairs of paths don't meet $S$?  Can we take $\hat{T}$ to always be computable (note the terminal nodes)?

A pair of paths $(f,g)$ meet $S$ if there is a pair $(\sigma, \tau) \in S$ with $\sigma$ extended by $f$ and $\tau$ extended by $g$.
A perfect $\omega$ branching tree is a tree  $T \subset \omega^{< \omega}$ a such that  $[T]$ is non-empty with no isolated paths and anytime $\sigma\hat{}i$ and any node with multiple immediate successors which extend to infinite paths has $\omega$ many immediate successors which extend to infinite paths, i.e., it's a tree which looks like $\omega^{< \omega}$.
I was thinking of this in terms of Ramsey theory since I'm asking for a set of paths (specified as the branches through a $\omega$ branching tree) such that all pairs have the same color (all extend pairs in $S$ or all fail to extend pairs in $S$).  Talking about it as Ramsey theory for $\omega$-branching trees was probably a bit confusing as it suggests that the tree is the thing that's supposed to be homogeneous.
Another way to think about the question that is being asked is whether you can achieve a (step towards) mutual genericity only by controlling the tree.

I think this is impossible due to some “oscillation” coloring, which is computable.

Let me answer the following question, which may miss the point of your formulation; let me know.
Is there a coloring of pairs of nodes in $\omega^{<\omega}$ in two colors such that there does not exist a monochromatic subtree $T$ with the following properties?

$T$ has no terminal nodes.
For every $t \in T$, there is an extension $s \geq t$ in $T$ and an infinite set of nodes, each of length $|s|+1$, which all extend to something in $T$.

Yes, there is such a coloring.  For a node $t$, let $\Sigma(t,n)$ be the sum of the range of $t \restriction n$.  For two nodes $t,s$, let $o(s,t)$ be the number of times that the “leader changes” as we go through the values of $\Sigma(t,n),\Sigma(s,n)$ for $n$ up to the length of the shorter one.
We can prove by induction that for any subtree $T$ as above, all values are obtained by the function $o$. Then we color by taking these values mod 2. Suppose we have a pair $s,t$ which each have infinitely many immediate successors, and $o(s,t) = k$.  Suppose $s$ holds the lead.  To have the lead change hands, let $s’\in T$ be any extension of $s$ that has infinitely many immediate successors and is at least as long as $t$, and then choose an immediate successor of $t$ whose value at the top is greater than $\Sigma(s’,|s|)$, and then extend this to $t’\in T$ that again has infinitely many immediate successors.  This yields $o(s’,t’)=k+1$.
Regarding the part about pairs of infinite paths “meeting” the partition, for any two $s,t$ with $o(s,t)$ even, extend to branches $f,g$ so that these branches meet the “even oscillation” set.  Similarly, we can find a pair of finite sequences with odd oscillation and extend to infinite paths, so the pair of paths meets the odd oscillation set.

This is an excellent answer of the natural Ramsey theory question here just explaining that I didn't accept it because it's not quite the same question.
I wasn't demanding the tree only have pairs of one color.  Rather, I was saying that a pair of paths gets color 0 if they extend a pair of strings in the set of pairs of strings S and color 1 if they don't extend such a pair (sorry yes that's asymmetric).  So the goal was that all pairs of paths through [T] either have color 0 or 1.
